# TYPO3 'Database' Search Extension

Tags: search, typo3

I´d like to implement something like a store finder by `ZIP-code in my TYPO3` website. I know there are Extensions that let users enter a `ZIP-code/adress` and find the nearest location but that's not what I´m after.

We deliver to our customers and follow fixed delivery plans. I want a user to enter his ZIP-code and the website should answer with one (or more) snippets with the delivery tables for the **matching driver (or drivers)**.

**TD;DR How do I search a multitude of content elements in TYPO3 and display only those with matching substrings?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybee just use Content Object "CONTENT" and use "select" in Typoscript:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html

And write your own select statement like:

```
"where = (title LIKE '%ZIP%')"
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html

An example, in german, but you will understand the typoscript part:

http://www.typo3wizard.com/de/artikel/das-content-objekt.html